# Convergence of improper integral $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{log(t)}dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

Convergence of improper integral

$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{log(t)}dt$

How do i start?

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: @CarlHeckman give me a hint

Comment: How are you supposed to handle integrals which have infinity as an endpoint? (Also, I'm not sure that that is the original problem; maybe the function was ${1\over t\ln t}$?)

Comment: @CarlHeckman problem doesnot have t

Comment: Do you know of some comparison theorem? What about the convergence of $\int_2^{+\infty}1/t\,dt$?

Comment: There's no elementary antiderivative for that integral, so you need to either find a function $\displaystyle f(x)<{1\over \ln x}$ such that $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty f(x)\,dx$ diverges, or a function $\displaystyle f(x)>{1\over \ln x}$ such that $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges.

Comment: @mickep by comparison with 1\t it shows divergent. is this right

Comment: I note that this is a very important integral in Number Theory, as the integral out to $n$ is asymptotic to the number of primes up to $n$.